# Controller not getting the record Id from aura:iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I've got an aura iteration that looks like this:

```
<aura:component description="ResourceTiles" implements="forceCommunity:searchInterface" controller="MainBrowser">

<aura:attribute name="resources" type="Resource__c[]" access="public" />

<aura:attribute name="resource" type="Resource__c" access="public" default="{'sobjectType': 'Resource__c', 'Name': 'Volvo XC90', 'Comment__c': ''}"/>
<aura:attribute name="selectedResourceId" type="Id" access="public" />
<aura:registerEvent name="ResourceSelected" type="c:ResourceSelected" />


<div class="slds-scrollable--x">
    <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer slds-table--striped">
    <thead>
        <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
            <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Car Selection"></div></th>
            <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Model">Car Model</div></th>
            <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Engine Information">Engine</div></th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.resources}" var="resource">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <lightning:button label="{!resource.Id}" aura:id="allButtons" onclick="{!c.changeColor}" value="{resource.Id}">
                    </lightning:button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!resource.Name}">
                        {!resource.Name}
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!resource.Comment__c}">
                        {!resource.Comment__c}
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </aura:iteration>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and a Controller that looks like this:

```
changeColor: function(component, event, helper) { 
    var resource = event.getSource().get("v.value");
    var event = component.getEvent("ResourceSelected");
    event.setParams({
        resourceId: resource.Id
    });
    event.fire();
```

Why am I receiving undefined for the resource Id? The label on the button itself is successfully displaying the record ID. I'm just having issues passing it to my controller - what am I missing here?

Comment: You have same variable name `resource` in your `aura:attribute` and `aura:iteration`. Try changing one of them?

Comment: Looks like you're assigning the `value` of the button to the resource's Id, but you're then taking `v.value.Id` within your event handler. Type mismatch?

Comment: try  this option in change color method ,,,var Val = event.target.value;  or try event.currentTarget.value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have same variable name `resource` in your `aura:attribute` and `aura:iteration`. Try changing one of them?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys. The issue was that I had an old attribute with the same name as the iteration variable. I just removed the  part.

Comment: You might accept Raul's answer if that was the solution to the issue.